# How to set a variable once a day in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Coniser a variable `list = ["A", "B",...]` as list of strings. I want to use a Javascript programm that picks three strings from this list once a day and writes it into a HTML field.

Currently I use

```
function getRandom(arr, n) {
var result = new Array(n),
    len = arr.length,
    taken = new Array(len);
if (n > len)
    throw new RangeError("getRandom: more elements taken than available");
while (n--) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
    result[n] = arr[x in taken ? taken[x] : x];
    taken[x] = --len in taken ? taken[len] : len;
}
return result;
}

smallList = getRandom(list, 3); 

var htmlTags = [
"tag1",
"tag2",
"tag3"
];
for (var i = 0; i < htmlTags.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(htmlTags[i]).innerHTML = smallList[i];
}
```

Now this list gets new entries  every time I refresh the website. Is there a way that `smallList` is only set once a day/hour/min/ in a pedriod of time only using javascript?

Comment: do the logic on a webserver.

Comment: Store the values in a cookie, after 24 hours set a new value and replace the cookie?

Comment: I mean if your page is just running 24/7 without interuption tan just `setTimeout(function() { smallList = getRandom(list,3)}, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)` would do the trick. This isn't a real solution though.

Comment: JavaScript lives in the browser -- so any new tab/window/refresh/whatever will trigger JS all over again.  This sounds like it'd be better suited for a server-side language (cron job, service, ...)

Comment: You could just pick a time of day to do this at, and compare in JS using moment (normalized timezone). Check to see if it's that time and run it. Which like my other comment is not a real solution. The real solution is doing this on a webserver.

Comment: Even if you get the page to remember if a set was generated for today (using cookie or local storage), then different visitors will see different tags). If you care about tag consistency, the only way to do it will be server side.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to:

- Pick three values from your list and show them on your web page
- Each day, pick three new values to show for the whole day
- Everyone who visits the page should see the same values regardless of client

As others have suggested, it would be a better candidate for a server-side task than client-side.

For example, you might have a server page which **checks for the existence of a value stored in cache**.  The cache would be **set to 24 hours.**  If the cache is not available, then **a new cache object is created** and given a half-life of 24 hours.  Inside the cache, you could also store the values you wish to retrieve.

Then, you could retrieve the cache and output the values. The particular implementation of the cache would depend on your server-side language.

Answer (score 0):

Store the list in localStorage or a Cookie. Also store the timestamp.

Use setTimeout(function(){...}, n) to examine the timestamp and update the values as needed.

If the page refreshes or is loaded anew, then perform the check on what is stored. If nothing exists, create your list and set the timestamp. If data does exist, then compare the timestamp and update the list as needed.

If you need the list to be consistent across users, then everything needs to be stored, examined and calculated on the server-side.

```
localStorage.savedData = {
    timestamp: new Date(),
    dataList: ['a','b','c']
}
```

To get the values from localStorage:

```
// you don't have to create variables, you can just use localStorage.[property] to get compare any value
let ts = localStorage.timestamp; // Date object
let dl = localStorage.dataList; // Array of values
```

For more information on localStorage see (or search the web) -> https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: could you elaborate in how to get the `timestamp` or `dataList`

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to retrieve the values from localStorage

Answer (score 0):

**OKAY: Via Stored Values (COOKIE, SESSION, LOCAL STORAGE, MEMORY):**

per user you'd have to use a cookie, session, or write to local storage in the browser.

for all users you'd have to use a server variable somewhere like a database, file, or memory.

you'd set the value to expire in a day and regenerate if expired.  this is the answer you will get from most people because it is the only way they know how to solve this, single set value polled from all locations.

**BETTER: Via Deterministic Pseudo-Random Number Generator Seeded with Date:**

or if you are really ambitious and don't want to rely on a value that you set somewhere, you could use or write a:
**deterministic pseudo-random number generator** that you seed off of the date.  Since deterministic pseudo-random generators produce reproducible "randoms" from the same seed, seeding the date gives you a unique seed per day, hence a unique random per day.

```js
function RC4(seed) {
 this.s = new Array(256);
 this.i = 0;
 this.j = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
  this.s[i] = i;
 }
 if (seed) {
  this.mix(seed);
 }
};
RC4.getStringBytes = function(string) {
 var output = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
  var c = string.charCodeAt(i);
  var bytes = [];
  do {
   bytes.push(c & 0xFF);
   c = c >> 8;
  } while (c > 0);
  output = output.concat(bytes.reverse());
 }
 return output;
};
RC4.prototype._swap = function(i, j) {
 var tmp = this.s[i];
 this.s[i] = this.s[j];
 this.s[j] = tmp;
};
RC4.prototype.mix = function(seed) {
 var input = RC4.getStringBytes(seed);
 var j = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < this.s.length; i++) {
  j += this.s[i] + input[i % input.length];
  j %= 256;
  this._swap(i, j);
 }
};
RC4.prototype.next = function() {
 this.i = (this.i + 1) % 256;
 this.j = (this.j + this.s[this.i]) % 256;
 this._swap(this.i, this.j);
 return this.s[(this.s[this.i] + this.s[this.j]) % 256];
};
function RNG(seed) {
 if (seed == null) {
  seed = '' + Math.random() + Date.now();
 } else if (typeof seed === "function") {
  // Use it as a uniform number generator
  this.uniform = seed;
  this.nextByte = function() {
   return ~~(this.uniform() * 256);
  };
  seed = null;
 } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(seed) !== "[object String]") {
  seed = JSON.stringify(seed);
 }
 this._normal = null;
 if (seed) {
  this._state = new RC4(seed);
 } else {
  this._state = null;
 }
}
RNG.prototype.nextByte = function() {
 return this._state.next();
};
RNG.prototype.uniform = function() {
 var BYTES = 7; // 56 bits to make a 53-bit double
 var output = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < BYTES; i++) {
  output *= 256;
  output += this.nextByte();
 }
 return output / (Math.pow(2, BYTES * 8) - 1);
};
RNG.prototype.random = function(n, m) {
 if (n == null) {
  return this.uniform();
 } else if (m == null) {
  m = n;
  n = 0;
 }
 return n + Math.floor(this.uniform() * (m - n));
};
RNG.$ = new RNG();
Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
 var mm = this.getMonth() + 1; // getMonth() is zero-based
 var dd = this.getDate();
 return [this.getFullYear(), !mm[1] && '0', mm, !dd[1] && '0', dd].join(''); // padding
};

// Using the Date like so will give you the same random between 40 and 50 for the same day
var rng = new RNG((new Date).yyyymmdd()); rng.random(40, 50);

// Test with dates
var rng = new RNG('20180301'); rng.random(40, 50);
var rng = new RNG('20180302'); rng.random(40, 50);
var rng = new RNG('20180301'); rng.random(40, 50);
```